# Accurate selection technique in edit mode

Tags: selection-tools

In a highly dense mesh, i want to select an organic shape, but, i don't want to use the Circle selection tool as creating a clean shape with the Circle selection is not possible. Is there a bezier selection method (like that in Photoshop) in blender?

Comment: I don't think any such selection method exists natively (without an addon) within blender - I think the closes you'll get is lasso select, perhaps with the aid of Ctrl + (+/-) buttons. Also, i'm not aware of any addon's that do this, I'm just leaving the possibility open for one to exist.

Comment: u could create a new curve object and draw the bezier shape and convert it into mesh then use the knife intersect tool to cut into the first mesh. then select the newly created edge loop and select inner region. is that not possible?

Comment: I don't know whether the numerous masking options in Sculpt Mode might be of interest?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie That could be an option but what if I have to select around an object. Knife project will simply cut the same shape through and through. For example I have to make a collar around a neck but it has to have a very specific shape around the neck. How do I go about it ?

Comment: @RobinBetts How to take those masking options to edit mode? Also hand painting a mask is still not accurate enough. A bezier curve is super accurate.